# using exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) or exit(EXIT_FAILURE) in AVR or any other microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, reset, watchdog

How does one use `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` in microcontroller C programming. I  know it works on application level C programs when you include `#include<stdlib.h>`.

The idea is to exit the main loop altogether when some unexpected value is returned, for example. 
What exactly would be the common approach in such a case? I could do a Reset but i want to see if somethings gone wrong in main. Is it a good practice to use `goto: exit_main` or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit()` is not the proper way to handle unexpected results in embedded platforms. You could use it, but it will cause a system reset. Either by design, or by timeout of the watchdog. Or just simply enter an infinite loop.

For example, ARM will do this, after a few library exit jumps.
(see for yourself in the simulator)

```
_sys_exit:
0x08000258 4901      LDR      r1,[pc,#4]  ; @0x08000260
0x0800025A 2018      MOVS     r0,#0x18
0x0800025C BEAB      BKPT     0xAB
0x0800025E E7FE      B        0x0800025E
0x08000260 0026      DCW      0x0026
0x08000262 0002      DCW      0x0002
```

[`BKPT`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABHCHGB.html) is a hardcoded breakpoint. Else, the [`B`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABEFHAE.html) instruction here will form an infinite loop.

On cricital errors that cannot be recovered you can instead do `NVIC_SystemReset()` on arm, or let the watchdog timeout. I believe AVR, as mention in an answer, does not have a dedicated system reset bit.

Comment: it does, however, have a watchdog.

Answer (score 3):

C11 5.1.2.1(2)

> The effect of program termination in a freestanding environment is implementation-defined.

exit() may or,may not, do what you want.

http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga137096a48cc0c731052cadfb69c39b34.html

looks like it will halt sort-of.

if you want a restart do this instead:

http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/FAQ_1faq_softreset.html

code:

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>

...

#define soft_reset()        \
do                          \
{                           \
    wdt_enable(WDTO_15MS);  \
    for(;;)                 \
    {                       \
    }                       \
} while(0)
```

Other microcontrollers will have other means of performing a software-triggered reset.

Comment: I learnt a while ago thats what Arduino does on exit(0), does a cli();//disabling interrupts and while(1)//Infinite loop, did not know it was valid for avr as well. In assembly, i would just write a goto and jump in an implemented routine, to leave the main loop.  I am just not sure if its a good practice in C.

Comment: the stub that runs before main() assumes that the processor has just come out of reset so all the I/O registers are in known states, so you can't just branch to that and always get a good result, atmel reccomends triggering the watchdog, (edit to aswer).